# convert integer to binary number in numba

Tags: numba

I'm using numba, and would like to convert an integer to a binary representation. In normal python I'd use bin() or np.binary_repr(). But these aren't supported in numba. Any advice? Should I just write a converter in numba from scratch?

Comment: These functions all return strings. Since Numba is not specialized to handle strings and is slower than pure Python for some string methods, perhaps this isn't the part of your code to accelerate with Numba in the first place?

Comment: The binary part is embedded inside a computationally expensive function, so I'd like it in numba. I ended up writing my own converter.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still interested this fn generate bin array via numba:

where size_of_bin is out length.

```
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np


@njit(fastmath=True)
def num_to_binary(number, size_of_bin = 32):
    out = np.zeros(size_of_bin)
    num = number
    index = 31

    for i in prange(size_of_bin):
        floatDivide = num // 2
        divide = num / 2
        if floatDivide != divide:
            out[index] = 1
    
        num = floatDivide
        
        index-= 1
        if index == -1 or floatDivide == 0:
            break

    return out
```

Comment: You have to be kidding.  Firstly, this is not the question that was asked.  Second, it would be very difficult to come up with a worse way to accomplish this task.  Floating division??  Third, `//` is the integer division, contrary to your variable names.  Are you not aware that `num & 1` will give you the low-order bit with no arithmetic needed?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30991091)